# Failed to configure a DataSource Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc

I have searched the forum, despite this no answer has worked.
I can't launch my application because I have an error message, I tried several solutions on the forum but the problem persists. I'm setting up this project but I've never used this kind of configuration

```
 Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-07-28 09:11:51.707 ERROR 9124 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

My app properties :

```
spring.profiles.active = dev;
```

My dev environment :

```
server.port = 8080
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=BuyMeDB
spring.datasource.password=123456
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans= false
```

My pom.xlm :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.RentAll</groupId>
    <artifactId>RentAllAPI</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>BuyMeAPI</name>
    <description>***</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEnconding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEnconding>
        <project.build.outputEnconding>UTF-8</project.build.outputEnconding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Starter web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring devtools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Starter test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring starter data jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- PostgreSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- HTTP Client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Hi, it seems that your application.properties is not observed by Springboot as you already set spring.datasource.url in that file. Can you share your application class annotated with @SpringBootApplication ? Try also to move what you have in "My dev environment" to your application.properties file.

Comment: `spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver` use this & check if it works.; looks like its missing in application.properties

Comment: Hi @AshishPatil, I added it, it doesn't work. Hi @GweltazNiquel,  
                                                                                       
                                                                                       
`@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class BuyMeApiApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(BuyMeApiApplication.class, args);
 }

}` my @SpringbootApplication